# How to deal gracefully with customization points of algorithms as well as constraints on their arguments?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, overloading, typeclass, customization-point

As an example, let's take the following algorithm for computing the longest common subsequence of two sequences, copied from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Haskell):

```hs
longest xs ys = if length xs > length ys then xs else ys
 
lcs [] _ = []
lcs _ [] = []
lcs (x:xs) (y:ys) 
  | x == y    = x : lcs xs ys
  | otherwise = longest (lcs (x:xs) ys) (lcs xs (y:ys))
```

`lcs` impicitly assumes that both arguments are of type `Eq a => [a]`; indeed, if I try to explicitly give the signature `lcs :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` an error occurs on the line where `x == y` is, whereas the signature `lcs :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]` works.

Now let's suppose I have two lists `l1` and `l2`, both of type `[(a,b)]`, and that I want the LCS between them, but in a way that uses the `==` operator in the definition of `lcs` only between the `snd`s of each element (obviously `b` is required to belong to `Eq` typeclass).

I could provide `lcs` with not only the two lists, but also with the equality operator, which in the specific example above would be `` (==) `on` snd ``. The signature of `lcs` would then be `(a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

However, this would force the user to provide the equality operator even in the trivial case that one wants to use a plain `(==)`, and wrapping the `(a -> a)` argument in a `Maybe` wouldn't help either.

In other words I feel that in the general case the constraint on the argument via `Eq a =>` is ok, but in other cases one might want to pass a custom equality operator removing that constraint, which makes me thing of function overloading.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply provide both – a custom-operator version `lcsBy`, and an `Eq a =>` version which is implemented in terms of that.

```
lcsBy :: (a->a->Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
...
lcsBy compOp (x:xs) (y:ys) 
 | compOp x y  = ...
 ...

lcs :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
lcs = lcsBy (==)
```

This is analogous to how the base library provides both [`maximum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum) and [`maximumBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy).

Comment: And `group`/`groupBy`, and many others, thinking about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Providing both is the simpler option, as @leftaroundabout wrote.

Still, in some specific cases, there are ways to call a function like

```
lcs :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

providing a custom equality operator like yours. For instance,

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Coerce
import Data.Function

newtype OnSnd a b = OnSnd { getPair :: (a, b) }
instance Eq b => Eq (OnSnd a b) where
   (==) = (==) `on` (snd . getPair)

lcsOnSnd :: forall a b. Eq b => [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
lcsOnSnd xs ys = coerce $ lcs (coerce xs) (coerce ys :: [OnSnd a b])
-- OR turn on TypeApplications, then:
-- lcsOnSnd = coerce (lcs @(OnSnd a b))
```

converts `[(a,b)]` to `[OnSnd a b]` using a zero-cost safe coercion, applies `lcs` (which will use the custom `==` of `OnSnd a b`), and converts the result back (zero-cost, again).

For this approach to work, however, `==` must be definable at the top-level, i.e. it can not be a generic closure depending on, say, an additional parameter to `lcsOnSnd`.

Comment: This `coerce` thing is interesting. However this solution still requires one to have two names, `lcs` and `lcsOnSnd`, to refer conceptually to the same thing, so I think the solution of simply having `lcs` and `lcsBy` is more practical.

Comment: @Enlico the point is that you would _not_ need to provide two versions, but _users_ of your function could hack into it to get it to behave as if an explicit comparison operator was passed, even though it's not. Incidentally, the `coerce` isn't strictly needed, it could also be done with a simple `map` but that would be slower. — Note also that [a direct way of passing explicit dictionaries](https://doi.org/10.1145/3242744.3242752) is being researched.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. So yours is the solution from the point of view of the user who uses a library which doesn't provide a customization point for the equality operator used in an algorithm, whereas the other answer is from the point of view of the library writer.

Comment: Your `OnSnd` (...well, actually, `OnFst`) is also available in the standard library as [`Arg`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Arg).